# How to mock AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync in unit test C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, authentication, azure-active-directory, moq

I have a method called `GenerateJWTToken()` to generate the bearer token. It uses `AuthenticationContext` However, `AuthenticationContext` does not have an interface. How do I mock it in the unit test?

Here's the code:

```
 private async Task<string> GenerateJWTToken()
    {
        var instance = _configuration["AzureAd:Instance"];
        var tenantId = _configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"];
        var clientId = _configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"];
        var clientSecret = _configuration.GetSection("appsecret").Value;
        var resource = _configuration["AzureAd:Resource"];

        var authority = string.Format("{0}{1}", instance, tenantId);
        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false);
        var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, credential);
        return result.AccessToken;
    }

  public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetResponseFromService(string userToken)
        {
            string endpoint = _configuration.GetSection("Service:Endpoint").Value;

            var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage()
            {
                Method = HttpMethod.Get,
                RequestUri = new Uri(endpoint)
            };

            var jwtToken = await GenerateJWTToken();
            httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwtToken);
            httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("token", userToken);

            HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await _rpsRequest.ExecuteAsync(() => httpRequestMessage, maxRetry);

            return httpResponseMessage 
        }
```

Let's assume we need to write unit test on `GetResponseFromService()`, could someone show me how to mock the `AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync` portion? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some [research](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2016/06/18/mocking-adal-for-unit-tests/), I realized that ADAL is not unit-testable, and we don’t test ADAL itself. Therefore, what I did was to extract the `GenerateJWTToken` in a new class that has its interface. And use dependency injection on the class that has `GetResponseFromService()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using in the GenerateJWTToken method Dependency Injection at all - you are creating objects ClientCredential and AuthenticationContext inside of the GenerateJWTToken - and that's why it's difficult for unit testing.
And breaks also Dependency inversion principle from SOLID, even if you have no "real interfaces".

Pass instances of the ClientCredential and AuthenticationContext as GenerateJWTToken and GenerateJWTToken parameters - that allows you to mock and unit test it well. Inject dependencies in that code instead of creating new objects.

**UPDATE**
Now I see that you are probably right, no option here besides some "fun" with Moq or wrapper class.
Main question - why you are using old, a bit deprecated ADAL, when there actually supported MSAL library? MSAL supports interfaces etc. https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-migration#differences-between-adal-and-msal-apps

From github:

> This library, ADAL for .NET, will no longer receive new feature
>   improvements. Instead, use the new library MSAL for .NET.

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet

Comment: But even if I inject dependencies, I can't mock it because there's no interface, isn't it?

Comment: @superninja I extended my answer